# Systemd stopped docker daemon for no obvious reason

Tags: systemd, docker

I'm trying to investigate why systemd sent a terminate signal to dockerd. This is related to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090971/docker-daemon-unexpectedly-exits/65091213#65091213).

```
$ journalctl -r

Dec 01 06:25:05 ip-10-38-4-210 dockerd[2218]: time="2020-12-01T06:25:05.867748396Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Dec 01 06:25:05 ip-10-38-4-210 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 01 06:25:03 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23453]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 01 06:25:01 ip-10-38-4-210 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Dec 01 06:25:01 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23454]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Dec 01 06:25:01 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23453]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 01 06:17:01 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23441]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 01 06:17:01 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23442]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 01 06:17:01 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23441]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 01 06:06:54 ip-10-38-4-210 CRON[23406]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

the last log entry before docker begins to stop is `CRON[23453]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`, does that seem related to you?

This is on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS on x86-64

Comment: You may be seeing some breakage from the ubuntu unattended upgrade, hearing other ubuntu users had similar issues today. There's also this Q to see a similar issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1538525/ubuntu-unattended-upgrades-stops-docker

Comment: I opened the following issue with Docker: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1155

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case, the thing telling systemd to stop the docker service appears to be the Ubuntu unattended-update service applying updates the the Ubuntu version of the containerd package. There's an open issue showing many others impacted by the same problem today:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/containerd/+bug/1870514

In that linked issue, the journal includes:

```
Apr 03 06:09:31 server systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
...
Apr 03 06:09:43 server systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
```

My recommended fix would be to install docker from the upstream Docker repositories which does not appear to have this issue:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: I'm having the same issue despite having the upstream Docker installed, is there any way to disable altogether the harming effects of the update service?

Comment: @Eugene not sure how you would have the same issue since the unattended updater only touches packages installed from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: @Eugene your comment timing suggests you were impacted by the bug fix that Ubuntu just pushed, see their linked issue for details.

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already an accepted answer but ...

> the last log entry before docker begins to stop is CRON[23453]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root, does that seem related to you?

Yes that does seem related, but not in this context, still answering here so that people running rootless docker coming across this in the future can get a solution.

I setup docker in rootless mode and tried
to host long-running docker containers in detached mode (`-d` flag) under my own user `ubuntu` (it was an AWS Lightsail instance). This was resulting in
my docker daemon and consequently my containers to gracefully shutdown.

### Solution

Enable Linger

```bash
sudo loginctl enable-linger $USER
```

Just to be sure, edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and add the following
lines to the end.

```ini
UserStopDelaySec=infinity
KillUserProcesses=no
```

Reboot your machine for the new config to take effect.

```
sudo reboot
```

### Culprit

The culprit happens to be `systemd` and how it handles processes started by login-sessions (which SSH terminal sessions happen to be). By default `systemd` sends `SIGTERM` to processes `10s` after the user logs out [according to the docs](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/logind.conf.5.en.html).

> `UserStopDelaySec=`
>
> Specifies how long to keep the user record and per-user service user@.service around for a user after they logged out fully. If set to zero, the per-user service is terminated immediately when the last session of the user has ended. If this option is configured to non-zero rapid logout/login cycles are sped up, as the user's service manager is not constantly restarted. If set to "infinity" the per-user service for a user is never terminated again after first login, and continues to run until system shutdown. Defaults to 10s.

> `KillUserProcesses=`
>
> Takes a boolean argument. Configures whether the processes of a user should be killed when the user logs out. If true, the scope unit corresponding to the session and all processes inside that scope will be terminated. If false, the scope is "abandoned", see systemd.scope(5), and processes are not killed. **Defaults to "no"**, but see the options KillOnlyUsers= and KillExcludeUsers= below.

Unless of course linger mode is enabled, [documented here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/loginctl.1.en.html#:%7E:text=enable%2Dlinger%20%5BUSER...%5D)

> `enable-linger [USER...], disable-linger [USER...]`
>
> Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables lingering for the user of the session of the caller.

I [wrote a blog about it](https://omranjamal.me/blog/005-keep-docker-rootless-alive/) with a bit more detail if you want to check it out.